# TeX live font error "Font gbk50 at 600 not found"

Tags: pdftex, texlive

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file gbk50): Font gbk50 at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

but I can find gbk50.tmf in my gkb folder, I just don't know why the error.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (“**why isn't this code working?**”) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: You need to install the real fonts manually. Read the readme of zhmetrics: https://ctan.org/pkg/zhmetrics

Comment: That's helpful. Thanks.